# Xcode scene editor bug - applyImpulse bug?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, skphysicsbody, skscene

I'm working on a new tvOS game using the scene editor in Xcode.

Is there any reason why applyImpulse is more powerful when further away from the scenes anchor point?

For example I can drive the car to the right of below scene and it spins faster than when back closer to the scenes anchor point. It's really odd. Has anyone else had this issue using scene editor? Seems that the physics are being amplified when further away from the scene anchor point.

How I'm applying impulse:

```
func playerRotateRight() {
  self.player?.physicsBody!.applyImpluse(CGVevtor(dx: 0, dy: -0.05), at: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20))
}

func playerRotateLeft() {
  self.player?.physicsBody!.applyImpluse(CGVevtor(dx: 0, dy: 0.05), at: CGPoint(x: -10, y: 20))
}
```

This is the scene:
[image]